# Remote scripting credentials

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, powershell-remoting

I've a strange problem that I can't understand. Maybe someone will be able to explain it to me. 
I'm trying to automate the installation of an app for SharePoint in a multitenant environment. I run the scripts on a remote machine like this:

```
$session =  New-PSSession -Name "Install App Session" -Authentication Credssp -Credential $InstallAccountCredentials  -ComputerName $frontend 
$installAppScriptPath = Join-Path $currentScriptPath "\SharePoint\InstallApp.ps1"
$job = Invoke-Command -Session $session -FilePath $installAppScriptPath -ArgumentList $customerUrl, $env:COMPUTERNAME -AsJob 
Wait-Job $job
```

Inside the InstallApp.ps1 I invoke the Import-SPAppPackage command but I get an "Access denied.
You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource." error. However, if I login to the machine with exactly the same credentials that are used as `$InstallAccountCredentials` and start the script, everything is working perfectly fine. The account that is used for running this script is an tenant admin account.

Is there something I miss in invoking the command?

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell remote doesn't work for a significant portion of the SharePoint cmdlets.  Use the client object model instead - you can invoke those methods from PowerShell as needed.